# I need help implement all pair shortest path algorithm into a code given

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I would really if someone could help implements the following algorithm into the following java code, ill also add the graph and sample output.
    [Java code sorry it wouldn't let me post][https://i.stack.imgur.com/meipB.png]
    [Algorithm}[https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE6Pv.png]
    [Graph][https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnSFk.png]
    [Output][https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpdoz.png]
    [Output][https://i.stack.imgur.com/geBJP.png]

Comment: It seems algorithm provided is not correct please verify it, because it is not giving L[] values as your attached screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Here I have posted implemented algorithm it seems it is not giving correct L[ ] values which are required for printing vertices. Please once have look is algorithm is correct or not before that i cant proceed.

```
    public class Graph {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] W = new int[][] { { 0, 2, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 2 }, { 0, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 2 },
                { 1, -1, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE }, { Integer.MAX_VALUE, -1, -1, 0 } };

        int[][] result = APSP1(W);

        display(4, result);
    }

    /**
     * @param w
     * @return
     */
    private static int[][] APSP1(int[][] w) {
        int n = w.length;
        LinkedList<int[][]> L = new LinkedList<int[][]>();
        L.add(w.clone());

//      display(1, L.get(0));

        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
            display(i, L.get(i-1));
            L.add(Extend(L.get(i - 1), w));
        }
        return L.get(n - 2);
    }

    /**
     * @param i
     * @param integers
     */
    private static void display(int i, int[][] arr) {
        System.out.println("L" + i);
        for (int[] ar : arr) {
            for (int a : ar) {
                if (a == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    System.out.print(" ~ ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" " + a + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * @param integers
     * @param w
     * @return
     */
    private static int[][] Extend(int[][] l, int[][] w) {
        int n = l.length;
        int[][] l$ = new int[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                l$[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    int n2;
                    if (l[i][k] == Integer.MAX_VALUE || w[k][j] == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                        n2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                    } else {
                        n2 = l[i][k] + w[k][j];
                    }
                    l$[i][j] = min(l[i][j], n2);
                }

            }
        }

        return l$;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer
     * @param i
     * @return
     */
    private static int min(int n1, int n2) {
        if (n1== Integer.MAX_VALUE && n2 == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        if (n1 >= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return n2;
        }
        if (n2 >= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return n1;
        }
        return n1 < n2 ? n1 : n2;
    }

}
```

In your geBJP image showing **ABDC** as shortest path[from A -> C] **A->(2)->B->(2)->D->(-1)->C** total cost = 3 but in graph **A->(2)->D->(-1)->C** is shortest path with cost = 1

Comment: That's the algorithm i received but you may make changes to it if you'll have to get the right output, thank you for you help.

Comment: Sorry that was an error, you are correct, its 3 instead of 1